# Keep editor in focus on mouse out?

Tags: scripting

When working in the scripting workspace I often move back and forth between the text, command window, and info editors. But what trips me up is focus follows the mouse. So If I'm working in the info editor but then try to `ctrl+c` something from the info editor while the mouse is over the text editor it does the `ctrl+c` on the text editor. I don't like this.

Is there a setting to keep editors in focus until another editor is clicked on?